# Create column, row value maps against several columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to create a new column in my `df`, this column's values will be mapped against values from several other columns.

Currently I have this:

```
df['PLATFORM'] = df['ID_1'].map(lambda x: 'ID_1_MATCH' if x == 9 else 0)
df['PLATFORM'] = df['ID_2'].map(lambda x: 'ID_2_MATCH' if x == 10 else 0)
df['PLATFORM'] = df['ID_3'].map(lambda x: 'ID_3_MATCH' if x == 11 else 0)
```

Using this approach, the value in the new column will be overwritten on the second and third map (where `x` matches the criteria of the lambda expression). I only want to update the column where, after the previous map, there remains to be a 0 value.

Is there a way to map values into a new column, dependent on the row values in several other columns, in a hierarchical manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['PLATFORM'] = np.where(df['ID_1']  == 9, 'ID_1_MATCH', 
                 np.where(df['ID_2']  == 10, 'ID_2_MATCH', 
                 np.where(df['ID_3']  == 11, 'ID_3_MATCH', 0 )))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1':[9,2,3,4],
                   'ID_2':[4,10,6,1],
                   'ID_3':[7,8,11,0]})

print (df)
   ID_1  ID_2  ID_3
0     9     4     7
1     2    10     8
2     3     6    11
3     4     1     0

df['PLATFORM'] = np.where(df['ID_1']  == 9, 'ID_1_MATCH', 
                 np.where(df['ID_2']  == 10, 'ID_2_MATCH', 
                 np.where(df['ID_3']  == 11, 'ID_3_MATCH', 0 )))
print (df)
   ID_1  ID_2  ID_3    PLATFORM
0     9     4     7  ID_1_MATCH
1     2    10     8  ID_2_MATCH
2     3     6    11  ID_3_MATCH
3     4     1     0           0
```

Comment: This works great - thanks! Is there a recommended limit on how many times to nest `np.where`? In this instance, I need nest up to 10 times.

Comment: I think there is no limit. Only it can be a bit slowier in big df.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bitmask to set only the rows where your condition is true.

This is more idiomatic (and faster) than any maps or lambdas.

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y'], data=[[0,1], [1,2]])
>>> df
   x  y
0  0  1
1  1  2
>>> df.ix[df['x'] % 2 == 0, 'match'] = 'x is even'
>>> df.ix[df['y'] % 2 == 0, 'match'] = 'y is even'
>>> df
   x  y      match
0  0  1  x is even
1  1  2  y is even
>>>
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach, except it overrides previously assigned values of the column. I'll definitely try to use this going forward if I know conditions do not overlap though. Thanks!